# Replicate or Mirror Column from one table to another table

Tags: sql, mirror, replicate

I have two tables, Table 1 with Sales Order Number, Sequence, and Line #.  Table 2 with the same Sales Order Number, Sequence, and Line #. Each table has other information besides the three main columns.  In Table 2, I want to mirror the Line # from Table 1. The Line # in Table 2 will be set to read only with extended properties.  Is there a way to accomplish this without doing a trigger on Table 1 to update Table 2?  Potentially, may be setting it with a default constraint but using a select to get the column value.

Comment: Just use a `join` to get the column value when you need it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you mean with in an alter table statement?

Comment: Having the data in two places would be bad practice. Adding a `join` would be the best option as @GordonLinoff states

Comment: @SoundWaves would you be able to provide an example of how it would look?  Table 2 is already created so I would need to alter it.